# email format is changing while generating vf to pdf

Tags: visualforce, sfdc-styleguide

it has to print :

> csedeep7@gmail.com

```
<apex:outputField value="{!contact1.email}"/>
```

it is printing like this :

> csedeep7@gmail.com [ Gmail]

can i know what is the issue

Comment: What data type is the 'email' field?

Comment: datatype is email standard field

Comment: Thats most odd, what does it do for other none gmail email addresses?

Comment: i have kept outputtext instead of outputField it is coming fine

Comment: Teja, if that solved your issue, feel free to post it as an answer rather than your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep outputtext instead of outputField it is coming fine

Comment: Please select an answer if it is a valid solution :)

Answer (score 1):

This occurs if you have the gmail integration in setup enabled, and you use outputField, the gmail link is automatically included. This is true regardless of PDF or HTML rendering mode, consistent with the standard UI. Either turn off the UI link, or use outputText or outputLink (if you want to make the email clickable).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using Salesforce Standard Email Field, try making use of text field.The Standard Salesforce Email link will have Email hyperlink if you have enabled gmail integration.

Answer (score 0):

AS @sfdcfox explained this is the issue with gmail Integration. You have to Deselect the "Gmail Buttons and Links" in Google Apps --> Settings if you don't want GMAIL Suffix